# How can we join common tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, view, common-table-expression, temp-tables

I have a complex query in Postgres which I am trying to convert in MySQL. The Postgres query has three chained queries. The first two create two common tables and the final query does a join on these two common tables. A simplified version of the query looks something like this . Is there a way to join these two common tables in MySQL ? I need the query to run for 5.6,5.7 and 8.0 so the new feature for CTE in 8.0 is not a solution.

```
(Select table1.y_id as year_id, 
       SUM(table1.total_weight) AS metric_value
       from (SELECT student_name,y_id,total_weight from student_metrics where y_id>10 ) table1
       group by year_id
       order by metric_value DESC
       limit by 5
 )table2
```

The third query should do a join of table1 and table2 on `table1.y_id = table2.year_id.`

To give a high level idea of what each of the query does:

1. Query 1 fetches data from the master table(Say, table 1) and stores 
   it in a common table based on some conditions
2. Query 2 groups and sorts the rows obtained in Query 1 based on a user specified column and limits it to top 'N'
3. Query 3 returns all details(on table 1) of only these N unique Ids(obtained from table 2) by perfoming a join on table1.id =
   table2.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply repeat the `table1` subquery:

```
select
    table1.*
from
    (select student_name,y_id,total_weight from student_metrics where y_id>10) as table1
    inner join (
        select tbl1.y_id as year_id, 
        sum(tbl1.total_weight) as metric_value
        from
            (select student_name,y_id,total_weight from student_metrics where y_id>10 ) as tbl1
       group by tbl1.y_id
       order by sum(tbl1.total_weight) desc
       limit by 5
       ) as table2 on table1.y_id = table2.year_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for this elegant hack. Was just wondering if there is a better way to rewrite this query even more efficiently ? I am okay with alternatives to CTE's also.

Comment: Efficiency of operation will depend on the ability of MySQL's query planner to recognize that the same operation is being done twice in this query, and actually carry it out only once.  You might run EXPLAIN with this query and see what the query plan looks like.  Otherwise, creating a separate view of the `table1` query and then referencing it twice in the main query probably would provide efficient execution as well as some structural simplification of the code--if the environment you're working in allows splitting this query up into two in that way.

Comment: Thanks, will look into the feasibility.